# Convert sorted array to binary tree in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Given a sorted array, convert it into a binary search tree in Java (Leetcode problem)

```
   /**
     * Definition for a binary tree node.
     * public class TreeNode {
     *     int val;
     *     TreeNode left;
     *     TreeNode right;
     *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
     * }
     */
    public class Solution {
        public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {
            if(nums.length == 0) {return null;}
            TreeNode ans = helper(nums, 0, nums.length);
            return ans;
        }

        public TreeNode helper(int [] nums, int start, int end){
            int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
            if(start == end){
                TreeNode lastNode = new TreeNode(nums[start]);
                lastNode.right = null;
                lastNode.left = null;
                return lastNode;
            }
            int mi = nums[mid];
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(mi);
            TreeNode left = helper(nums, start, mid - 1);
            TreeNode right = helper(nums, mid + 1, end);
            newNode.left = left;
            newNode.right = right;
            return newNode;
        }
    }
```

I get a stackoverflowerror at the line:

```
TreeNode left = helper(nums, start, mid - 1);
```

But I don't see why I get the error?

I tried it out with the sample array: `[1, 2, 3]` and I got the error. **Can someone help me out on why this is happening?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What happens when `start` = 0 and `end` = 1?

Comment: @JoeC, in the case I tested, `[1, 2, 3]`, the case with start = 0, end = 1 never appeared... or did it? Where?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the condition (start == end) doesn't happens and recursive still calling

Try to make it (nums.length -1) instead of nums.length

Comment: It passes some cases, but I get an error with case: `[1, 3]`

Comment: That's because the length - 1 will be 1 this is the only special case

Answer (score 0):

I've modified code to make it work. At first, I've uncommented the enclosing `TreeMode` class and made `Solution` as inner class. Then I've removed `public` keyword from class declarations due to compilation error.

I've added more arguments for `TreeNode` constructor. To create a `TreeNode` object called `root`, a constructor is called with three arguments by the `new` operator inside method `helper` of the class `Solution`. Added `if`-condition inside `helper` method to avoid `Memory Limit Exceeded`.

And changed `nums.length` parameter to `nums.length-1`. As correctly mentioned by [Fady Saad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155317/8370915).

An algorithm needs to take the element from the middle of an array and put it as the root node. And, after that, an array is divided into a left and right side. The central element of the left side becomes a left node, while the central element of the right side of the table becomes the right node.

To understand and analyze deeply, you can debug it.

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode y, TreeNode z) {
        val = x;
        left = y;
        right = z;
    }
}


class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        TreeNode ans = helper(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
        return ans;
    }

    public TreeNode helper(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;

        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(nums[mid], null, null);
        root.left = helper(nums, start, mid - 1);
        root.right = helper(nums, mid + 1, end);

        return root;
    }
}
```